# WCF REST service - Route all requests to one operation

Tags: wcf, rest

Is there a way I can register a route to handle all URL formats and route them to a specific service operation?

For example:

```
www.somedomain.com 
www.somedomain.com/anything
www.somedomain.com/anything/anything
```

and so on...

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE:** That was silly. Here's how to do it:

```
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "*")]
```

However, this poses another problem for me. Lets say I use the following URL:

```
www.somedomain.com/Segment1/Segment2
```

It gets mapped to my function (marked with the above attribute) - but the incoming request URL looks like:

```
www.somedomain.com/Segment1
```

The rest of the URL is nowhere to be found.

Does anyone know how to access the original URL? before the template matching changes it?

Thanks.

Comment: yes but ill need to update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without taking anything away from syneptody's solution ( above) which seems stronger and more robust, I managed to work out the UriTemplate I was looking for:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/*")]
```

This matches the first '/' after the domain and provides the rest of the url in 
    WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch

That's exactly what i was looking for. 
Just incase anyone ever looks for this....

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that might be best served at the administration level.  It may be tempting to try registering a default route but in this case I would recommend looking at the IIS URL Rewrite module:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

This module is very powerful and can be used to rewrite URLs based on wildcards or regex expressions. This would allow you to define a rule that rewrites any URL that comes to www.somedomain.com to a canonical address of your service operation.

As an example, to simply rewrite any request that comes in to somedomain.com to somedomain.com/Segment1 you could try something like the following. (you may have to play with the wildcard)

```
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^somedomain\.com*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.somedomain.com/Segment1" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Keep in mind that this tool is immensely powerful and if you read the documentation you will see that you could accommodate almost any permutation of patterns.

Here's another article that gives some examples:

http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply !  Im not sure i fully understand this direction - what url would i rewrite to ? my opration is mapped to anything written in the first URL segment so what would the rewritten URL look like ?  thanks again !

Comment: I updated the answer with a basic example that should map any request that comes to the domain www.somedomain.com to www.somedomain.com/Segment1  I believe this will ensure that no matter how your site is addressed Segment1 will always service the request.

Comment: This does not work on windows server 2003. We switched server (yes I know about time), but are faced with the accepted answer since url redirect seems to require iis 7.